# Mysql stops working in my ubuntu machine 13.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb, mysql-error-2002

I am facing this weird issue. Suddenly mysql stops working and i am getting error log in **/var/log/mysql/error.log**

**

```
140501 17:21:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140501 17:21:09 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140501 17:21:09 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140501 17:21:09 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140501 17:21:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140501 17:21:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140501 17:21:10 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-creating-innodb.html
140501 17:21:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140501 17:21:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140501 17:21:10 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140501 17:21:10 [ERROR] Aborting

140501 17:21:10 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**

Its very itching problem as I can write a single code without myqsl connection. How to solve this issue.

PS: Sorry Ubuntu fellas as I am using 13.04 unsupported version, I have already installed 14.04 and will move to it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

After going through lots of suggestions I found in stackoverflow and other mysql related websites, I did not success to fix this issue. then I reconfigure my mysql installations and voila its working now.

Command I used is

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```